# Facebook Graph API: Displaying JSON-data from console on HTML webpage

Tags: javascript, html, json

New to Facebook's API and JavaScript altogether, so please bear with me.

I am currently trying to:

1. Retrieve data about the events of a Facebook-page using the Facebook Graph API. Using the JavaScript SDK.
2. Insert the name, date and URL of the next three events on a otherwise static HTML website (see picture below)

Status of that right now is that I successfully get the JSON-data of the Facebook page's event, and that it shows up in the browser console when I run `console.log(response)`.

But, as a JS-novice, how can I get that data (and preferably just for the *next three events*) do actually show up in my HTML as intended in the picture below?

Looking forward to seeing your responses!

[image: Text]

**HTML**

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId            : 'BLAH',
        autoLogAppEvents : true,
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v10.0'
    });
    FB.api(
        '/BLAH/events?fields=start_time,id,name',
        'GET',
        {access_token:'BLAH BLAH',
        },
        function(response) {
            console.log(response)
        }
    );

};
```

```html
<a href="#" class="d-inline-flex text-decoration-none align-items-center my-1 hvr-bubble-float-right">
  <div class="arrangement-dato text-white text-center lh-1 d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center">
      <div class="dato">13</div>
      <div>feb</div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="ms-2 link-dark">Event name</h2>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="d-inline-flex text-decoration-none align-items-center my-1 hvr-bubble-float-right">
  <div class="arrangement-dato text-white text-center lh-1 d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center">
    <div class="dato">4</div>
    <div>mar</div>
  </div>
  <h2 class="ms-2 link-dark">Event name</h2>
</a>
<a href="#" class="d-inline-flex text-decoration-none align-items-center my-1 hvr-bubble-float-right">
  <div class="arrangement-dato text-white text-center lh-1 d-flex align-items-center flex-column justify-content-center">
    <div class="dato">12</div>
    <div>apr</div>
  </div>
  <h2 class="ms-2 link-dark">Event name</h2>
</a>
```

**Example of returned JSON-data in console**

```
id: "1234567890"
name: "Event name"
start_time: "2021-02-20T09:00:00+0100"
```

**PS:** I'm aware that I should not run the access token on the client side. This is an issue that I will fix later.

**PPS:** It doesn't *actually* say 'BLAH' in my JS-code.

Comment: There is little reason to tag a question like this with `facebook-graph-api` (tag removed) - your question is not about that, it is about using JSON in general … and then, not even that, of course, it is really about how to navigate in a nested PHP data structure.

Answer (score 1):

What framework are you using? If you're using plain JavaScript you can do it this way:

```
document.getElementById(<<id of text>>).innerText = response.name;
var date = new Date(response.start_time);

document.getElementById(<<id of green circle>>).innerHTML = date.getDate() + "<br>" + date.getMonth();
```

If you're using jQuery you replace document.getElementByID() by $('#' + <>) and change innerText by .text(response.name) and innerHTML by .html(date.getDate() + "
" + date.getMonth()).

I expect the data is an array, then you have to loop thru your response object (search for loop).

If you are using Vue, React or Angular you'll have to look on Google on how to change it there.